# How to properly configure WAMP server

Tags: apache, http, wamp

I installed WAMP server on windows 7 computer and then hosted a website.

Unfortunately when more than 30-40 computers try to access the website it shows the "Service unavailable" screen. Before this screen is being displayed it shows the "Connecting..." label trying to load the page.

My internet is very very fast. Also i tried to transfer files over skype from remote computers to the server where the site is hosted and all works fine.

Pinging the server shows excellent result without no drops.

So i guess there must be something about the WAMP server. **Any idea how can i configure it so it accepts more connections simultaneously?**